# Leaflet GeoJSON display

Tags: javascript, geojson, leaflet

I have encountered a task, that requires usage of leaflet js library with geojson as data storage. And almost immediately, following problem being encountered: polygon created from geojson object doesn't display on map. While polygon, created by native leaflet method - works perfectly.

Here's my code:

```
        var map = new L.Map('map');
        var bingLayer = new L.BingLayer('AhVaalRWmmprMAMHj6lw18ALO-iVnIGzvkq7gYAX3U_bisCT8Q_lgGV25YOa0kiV', 'Aerial');
        map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.09), 13).addLayer(bingLayer);
        var polygon = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                    "style": {
                        "color": "#004070",
                        "weight": 4,
                        "opacity": 1
                    }
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[
                    [51.509, -0.08],
                    [51.503, -0.06],
                    [51.51, -0.047],
                    [51.509, -0.08]
                ]]
            }
        };
        var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(polygon);
        map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

As you can see, it almost copies an example, provided by leaflet. And does not work. I am completely bugged by this trouble, and will be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that in `GeoJSON` spec, coordinates should be passed in the form `[lon, lat]` while Leaflet uses `[lat, lon]` for its objects. Just change it to `[-008, 51.509]`, etc., and you should be fine. :)

Comment: According to the leaflet documentation (link in the comment above), all coordinates seem to be (lon, lat)

Comment: Can u help me out -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380886/adjusting-the-drawn-object-in-map-automatically-using-leaflet-geojson-property

Comment: Here is the GeoJson spec: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions, quote - **A position is represented by an array of numbers. There must be at least two elements, and may be more. The order of elements must follow x, y, z order (easting, northing, altitude for coordinates in a projected coordinate reference system, or longitude, latitude, altitude for coordinates in a geographic coordinate reference system).**

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add some of my points-

Just a matter of confusing and contradictory standards.

When talking about geographic locations, we usually use Lat-long.

The `map.setView` takes a `l.LatLong` as an input, where the first cordinate is a `Latitude`, and the second is `Longitude`.

Example :- Hence when you want `52.23N, 4.97E`, you pass in `[52.23943, 4.97599]`

The GeoJSON standard says that for any point, the first parameter is the `X Coordinate (i.e. Longitude)` and second parameter is the `Y coordinate (i.e. Latitude)`;

Hence when you want `51.505N, 0.09E` in `GeoJSON`, you need to pass  `[-0.09, 51.505]`

```
var map = new L.Map('map');
var bingLayer = new L.BingLayer('AhVaalRWmmprMAMHj6lw18ALO-iVnIGzvkq7gYAX3U_bisCT8Q_lgGV25YOa0kiV', 'Aerial');
map.setView(new L.LatLng(-0.09, 51.505), 13).addLayer(bingLayer);
var polygon = {
    "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
        "style": {
            "color": "#004070",
                "weight": 4,
                "opacity": 1
        }
    },
        "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
            [
                [51.509, -0.08],
                [51.503, -0.06],
                [51.51, -0.047],
                [51.509, -0.08]
            ]
        ]
    }
};
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(polygon);
map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

You can adjust your view by modifying this..

```
map.setView(new L.LatLng(-0.09, 51.505), 13).addLayer(bingLayer);
```

to

```
map.setView(new L.LatLng(-008, 51.509), 13).addLayer(bingLayer);
```

I think this explanation will help !! For More [Click Here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html)