# adjusting the drawn object in map automatically using leaflet 'Geojson' property 'getbound'

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am using leaflet in my project for displaying objects and elements in map (Open source map). I have drawn some objects in my map using `Geojson` styles 
While using `Geojson` with the leaflet js implementation I am not able to use `getBounds` option properties.

But normally if I am not using `Geojson` and its features I am able to use this option `getBounds` mentioned below.

```
var group = new L.featureGroup([marker, circle, polygon, rectangle]);
//alert(group);
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

My set view code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.75621, -104.99404], 13);
```

Whenever a page loaded it should find the objects and draw elements (trace components) and adjust its Zooming.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajswarnkar/RT5w5/)

Comment: after checking your fiddle, the geoJson function couldn't complete because there is an error. `L.geoJson(someGeojsonFeature, { ... }` <-- what is someGeojsonFeature ?

Comment: @KarelG geojsonFeature is referring for some coordinates which is displaying in map.. I will check for error

Comment: @CrazyAboutJavascript - am I correct in understanding your question as:  How can I set the bounds of my map equal to the bounds of my featureGroup?  (Sort of like a zoomTo method for your featureGroup)

Comment: @sfletche yes correct.. In some home.. I went through the documentation but able to figure it out..

Comment: Crazy, realizing that a goal of stackoverflow is `to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming` how about publishing the answer to your own question now that you've read the documentation?  One comment.. I don't see anywhere in your jsfiddle where the setbounds call is used. Am I missing something?  So what is the magic code to recenter and resize the map so it encompasses all of the added features?  thanks.